# Does QEMU support OpenBSD ALTQ feature of pf?

Tags: qemu, openbsd, qos

Does anyone have experience running `OpenBSD` within `QEMU`? I am interested in building a "virtual switch" (bridge) and using the quality of service features of pf, in particular ALTQ? The ALTQ main page says that it must supported by the network card. What kind of support is needed? Does it work with QEMU virtual network cards, e.g. if I want to build a virtual network? I am interested in your experiences.

Answer (score 2):

i think you are good to go. The truth is that i haven't run altq explicitly on 
any of my VMs but i can't think of a reason that it wouldn't work.

Finally keep in mind that in post 5.1 releases altq is being reworked completely.
check out [the presentation by henning@](http://quigon.bsws.de/papers/2012/bsdcan/index.html)